# Iterate list of objects and get average

Tags: java

Is there any way to get an average here via one iteration? I can do it with regular "For loop" but want to use stream instead.

```
final Double ratingSum = ratingCount.stream().mapToDouble(RecommendRatingCount::getRatingSum).sum(); 
final Double countSum = ratingCount.stream().mapToDouble(RecommendRatingCount::getCount).sum();
return ratingSum /countSum;
```

Comment: In general, `.summaryStatistics()` can be used to get the average, but since it looks like each element might have multiple counts, that might be tricky.  Still doable, just requiring a custom Collector.  Is there a way to get each individual rating rather than the sum?

Answer (score 1):

Decompose each object into separate ratings, each value being rating/count, by first expanding out each object `count` times, then converting each to its discounted value, then summarise all such values:

```
double average = ratingCount.stream()
    .flatMap(rrc -> generate(() -> rrc).limit(rrc.getCount()))
    .mapToDouble(rcc -> rcc.getRatingSum() / rcc.getCount())
    .summaryStatistics().getAverage();
```

Comment: It returns `1.0` for `[{ratingSum=1, count=2}]`.  But OPs returns `0.5`.

Comment: Can you explain please what is going on here: 
```.flatMap(ratingCount -> Stream.generate(() -> ratingCount).limit(ratingCount.getCount()))```

Comment: @Alexey `flatMap()` turns a stream of a streams into a single stream. It does this by using a function, that you provide to the flatMap method, that converts each object into a stream, then it concatenates those streams.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Java 12 or higher is used a teeing collector

```
  return 
  ratingCount.stream()  
             .collect(Collectors.teeing(    
                         Collectors.summingDouble(RecommendRatingCount::getRatingSum),  
                         Collectors.summingDouble(RecommendRatingCount::getCount),  
                         (sum, count) -> sum / count));
```

Comment: Thank you, but need to update java 11 first :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your RatingCount is a natural number.

```
return ratingCount.stream()
            .flatMapToDouble(a -> DoubleStream.concat(DoubleStream.of(a.getRatingSum()),
                            DoubleStream.generate(() -> 0).limit((long) a.getCount() - 1)))
            .average().orElse(0);
```